# javascript não está sendo carregado no navegador do celular

Tags: javascript

Estou tendo um problema esquisito no meu javascript, quando eu executo no navegador do pc funciona normal, mas quando eu executo no navegador do celular o javascript não reconhece minhas funções/variáveis.

```
class UusarioDAO{
    static async trazDadosUsuario(id){
        const dados = await 
        firebase.database().ref("usuarios/"+id).once("value");
        usuario.setUsuarioId(dados.val().usuarioId);
        usuario.setNome(dados.val().nome);
        usuario.setPais(dados.val().pais);
        usuario.setFoto(dados.val().foto);
        usuario.setEmail(dados.val().email);
        usuario.setFotoProvedor(dados.val().fotoProvedor);
        usuario.setCaminho(dados.val().caminho);
        usuario.setToken(dados.val().token);
        usuario.setUsuarioGostos(dados.val().gostos);
        pais = dados.val().pais;
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>resolve("resolvido"));
    }
}
class EventoDAO{
    static async listar(id){

        let eventos = [];

        const eventosRef = firebase.database().ref("eventos/"+pais);


        try{
            const user = await userRef.once("value");

            const categorias = await eventosRef.once("value");
            categorias.forEach(auxEvento=>{
                const evento = new Evento();
                evento.setId(auxEventos.val().id);
                evento.setTitulo(auxEventos.val().titulo);
                evento.setDescricao(auxEventos.val().descricao);
                evento.setHorario(auxEventos.val().horario);


               eventos.push(evento);
           });



        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>resolve(eventos));

        }catch(erro){

            console.log(erro);

            Notificacao.erro(erro);

         }
    }

 }
try{
    await UsuarioDAO.trazDadosUsuario(user.uid,null);
    const eventos = await EventoDAO.listar(user.uid);
    escondeLoading()

    eventos.forEach(evento=>{

        criaLista(evento,"todos");

    });    

    defineLanguage();
    if(navigator.language.split("-").shift()=="en"){
        $(".btn-success").css("padding","30px 30px");
        $(".btn-primary").css("padding","30px 8px");
    }
}catch(erro){
    console.log(erro);
    Notificacao.erro(erro);
}

}
```

[image: como mostra no pc][image: como mostra no celular]

Comment: você definiu o nome da classe UusarioDAO e tá usando UsuarioDAO, percebe que existe um `u` a mais

Comment: foi um erro só aqui na pergunta . no meu código não ta assim não, mas o problema é que funciona no navegador normal, mas quando eu tento pelo celular não vai. o link caso você queira testar no seu https://apptcc-6f556.firebaseapp.com/eventos.html

Comment: Não é um problema esquisito, rs. O que acontece é que vc tá usando recursos mais recentes do javascript sem antes buildar na versão estável. Em suma, você está utilizando `class` como se fosse algo padrão em todos os browsers, mas infelizmente ainda não é. Se quiser algo crossbrowser, você vai precisar transpilar seu código com babel ou algum outro compiler.
Abs

Comment: não entendi, porque eu testei no chrome do pc e no chrome do celular também, mas não funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boom diaa!

Bom, provavelmente você usará ou já está utilizando o Cordova para conseguir rodar esse site como App em uma Web View.
Uma das coisas que tem que se atentar é na versão do Ecmascript utilizado e na versão de ambos os navegadores, tanto do celular, quando do pc. Seu código está utilizando a versão ES6 do Javascript, para que você não tenha problema de compatibilidade,precisa converter para ES5 utilizando o Babel.

Um exemplo da implementação do Babel, você pode ver neste link.
[How to Convert ES6 into ES5 using Babel](https://medium.com/@SunnyB/how-to-convert-es6-into-es5-using-babel-1b533d31a169)

Você pode usar esse coverter seu código online, para fazer testes, neste link.

[Babel Online](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=Q&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2017%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.9.0&externalPlugins=)

Comment: cara é isso mesmo, eu uso o cordova, esse babel é muito interessante, mas não resolveu meu problema, mas eu testei no browser do android sem usar esse babel e funcionou, então acho que o problema ta no IOS